# document mouseover & mouseout firing multiple times - should just fire once

Tags: javascript

I need to fire two events. One when the cursor enters the document and when he leaves the document. Right now i have a problem that the events also fire when i use the cursor inside the document, you can see this in the console of my fiddle.

How is it possible to just fire the events when i enter and leave the document?

```
let cursor = document.getElementById('cursor');

function onMousEnter() {
    cursor.classList.add('is-active');
    console.log("Enter!");
}

function onMouseLeave() {
    cursor.classList.remove('is-active');
    console.log("Out!");
}

document.addEventListener('mouseover', onMousEnter);;
document.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseLeave);

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';  
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k81zbdmj/1/

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `mouseenter` instead of `mouseover`.
2. Use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`.

The difference between those is that `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` *don't* bubble. So whenever you move your cursor over or out of a child, those *won't* trigger the event.